# How to setup google calendar api push notifications in local

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

I would like to be able to setup google calendar push notifications in my local. Google calendar documentation requires [domain registration](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#registering-your-domain).

I would like to know if there is any workaround to make this work in the local environment using a virtual host accessible only in my local machine.

If that's impossible I would like to know how to at least make the development easier, if I have to setup the web-hook in a remote machine.

I am using a standard php stack for development LAMP.